# How to refresh chatting page with ajax if user have new message?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Now I create chatting app with Laravel. And can send message and refresh messageBox container after sending message via ajax. But I can't refresh my chat partner page if I'll send to him new message and conversely refresh page if my chat partner send to me new message. In my database I have field with message seen status. If message not seen it will be 0 conversely 1. How I can refresh page or div content if have new message via ajax?
Here my sending code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username;
    var submitButton;
    var textarea;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        username = $('#username').html();
        textarea = $('#texxt');
        submitButton = $('.send');

        $(textarea).keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                sendMessage();
                $('body').load('').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });

    function sendMessage(){
        var message = $('#texxt').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        if(message.length > 1){
            $.post('/message',{
                message: message,
                id: user_id,
                _token:'{{csrf_token()}}'
            },
            function(data){
                $('#texxt').val('');
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that you need to think about: https://socket.io

All Jobs are triggering events, so you can use this event to show message to another user, or get new messages action... But to do that you need to use sockets :)

Comment: Also here you have laracast about it
https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io

Answer (score 0):

With `Ajax`, you have to check on a regular basis with `setInterval` and see if a message has arrived and then do something with it if so:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON("/my_check_message.php",
            {user_id: user_id}, 
            function (answer) {
               if answer.new_messages.length>0){
                  //do something
               }), 5000)
```

It assumes that you return from your php page `answer.new_messages` as an array (you can have multiple new messages)

**EDIT**  `5000` stands for 5000 milliseconds. So this will make checks every 5 seconds. Adapt it to your needs!

Comment: This is inefficient compared to a socket.io system. By creating a state machine you may create extra processes when the system is truly idle.

Comment: The question was about `Ajax` so this is the answer I gave. However I agree socket.io would be a more appropriate solution event thought it needs some implementation work.

Comment: Totally agree I should have stated that you answered the poised question. Just was commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel echo which facilates a socket.io server that you can broadcast events in the backend to a frontend client using echo.